# Ruby gem to quickly validate partial HTML snippets?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a customized quasi-CMS in Rails, and we'd like to have one field that is editable as an HTML fragment in code (the admin interface will be using CodeMirror on the frontend). When it's presented to the end user, it will just be `html_safe`'d and inserted into a div. We trust our content editors not to be malicious, but it would be helpful to ensure they're creating valid HTML so they don't break the page, especially since they're relatively new to coding!

As a first attempt, I'm using `Hash.from_xml` and rescuing exceptions as a custom validator. But is there a better and/or more-optimized way (i.e. a gem) to check that it is valid HTML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of validation, perhaps it's worth to use Nokogiri which is capable of fixing markup:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = '<div><b>Whoa</i>'
Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html).to_html
#=> "<div><b>Whoa</b></div>"
```

Comment: This seems perfect for what we're looking for - didn't know that Nokogiri could handle fragments! Also, thinking about fixing markup, I found https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/ which is built on this Nokogiri functionality and allows finer-grained control over what kind of markup is allowed. Thanks!

Comment: There is shorter syntax: `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html).to_html`

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) library (and [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri)) to create a validator in your model. Using Nokogiri on fragments isn't perfect (so you might want to add the ability to override the validator) but it will catch many obvious errors that might break the page.

Example (assuming your model attribute/field is called `content`):

```
validate :invalid_html?

def invalid_html?
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(self.content) do |config|
    config.strict
  end
  if doc.errors.any?
    errors.add(:base, "Custom Error Message")
  end
end
```

Comment: what is `:base`? How to really add an error messages with actual error message that nokogiri provides?

Comment: `:base` signifies an error against an entire model. You can also mark the error against a specific field. If the field is content, the following would might actually be better `errors.add(:content, "Custom Error Message")`.

Comment: If you want to add Nokogiri's errors then you could process `doc.errors` and add them in whatever way you felt was useful.
To add each error to the model you could do `doc.errors.each { |nokogiri_error| errors.add(:content, nokogiri_error) }`. I'm not certain what Nokogiri errors look like or whether that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want https://github.com/libc/tidy_ffi or http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/HTML/WhiteListSanitizer (class method `sanitize`)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're looking for?: [be_valid_asset](https://github.com/unboxed/be_valid_asset).

Comment: It seems this [calls out to an external service](https://github.com/unboxed/be_valid_asset/blob/master/lib/be_valid_asset/be_valid_markup.rb), and I'd rather rely on something internal, but it's a good start!